# How to select a value with results from another column

Tags: c#, mysql

i am using C# and i need to develop a check system for a mysql user and password.
So far what ive come up with is this and the error i get is that it is the wrong syntax...

```
public bool VerifyUser(string username, string password)
{
    string returnValue = "";

    string Query = "SELECT Pass FROM Base_Character WHERE User='" + username + "'";

    MySqlCommand verifyUser = new MySqlCommand(Query, this.sqlConn);

    try
    {
        verifyUser.ExecuteNonQuery();

        MySqlDataReader myReader = verifyUser.ExecuteReader();

        while (myReader.Read() != false)
        {
            returnValue = myReader.GetString(0);
        }

        myReader.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception excp)
    {
        Exception myExcp = new Exception("Could not verify user. Error: " +
            excp.Message, excp);
        throw (myExcp);
    }

    if (returnValue == password)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: How I'd go about this: Make the query to check for User AND password. If you get a result, you will know, that the correct password has been supplied, if not, then you'll know that the password is wrong. That way, you don't have to bother with the return value. Also, what error message are you getting?

Comment: What line is the compiler error on?

Comment: I do not know anything about MySQL to help you but you should really read this article because your code is in danger of the SQL Injection attack...http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163917.aspx

Comment: Also your final `if` block is backwards, unless you want to return `false` if the passwords match.

Comment: This line isn't needed verifyUser.ExecuteNonQuery();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ExecuteNonQuery` is for DELETE, INSERT and UPDATE. Whenever you want data returned as rows from database, use `ExecuteReader`

Your query should check the username and password together, if they exist in one record then the row is returned else nothing is returned.

You still need more to learn about coding/database programming using .Net

```
public bool VerifyUser(string username, string password)
{
    bool returnValue = false;
    string Query = "SELECT 1 FROM Base_Character WHERE User='" + username + "' AND pass='"+password+"'";

    try
    {
        MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(Query, this.sqlConn);

        MySqlDataReader myReader = command.ExecuteReader();

        if(myReader.Read())
        {
            returnValue = true;
        }

        myReader.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception excp)
    {
        throw;
    }

    return returnValue;
 }
```

You should probably not throw a custom exception since you are using boolean

```
if(VerifyUser("user123", "******"))
{
   //Congratulations
}
else
{
   //Unable to log you in
}
```

Comment: you still have command.ExecuteNonQuery(); line in your answer although you are suggesting that it is an error

Comment: I suggest you check for how to rethrow exception: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12847637/throwing-a-new-exception-best-practice for

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys, but this calls for a custom encryption that mysql cant hold or process, my main error was ovrlooking the executenonquery(), so i had to make the code like this:

```
if (AuthorizeTools.Encrypt.Password(Database.getPassword) != Password) //Password is already encrypted
```

Then set the mysql function to:

```
public string getPassword(string username)
        {
            string returnValue = "";
            string Query = "SELECT Pass FROM Base_Character where (User=" +
                "'" + username + "') LIMIT 1";

            MySqlCommand checkUser = new MySqlCommand(Query, this.sqlConn);

            try
            {
                checkUser.ExecuteNonQuery();

                MySqlDataReader myReader = checkUser.ExecuteReader();

                while (myReader.Read() != false)
                {
                    returnValue = myReader.GetString(0);
                }

                myReader.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception excp)
            {
                Exception myExcp = new Exception("Could not grab password: " +
                    excp.Message, excp);
                throw (myExcp);
            }
            return (returnValue);
        }
```

Comment: while (myReader.Read() != false) ? There's an easier way to express that, and a better way. if (myReader.Read()) {}. Had to read your version three times.