# Throwing a New Exception Best Practice

Tags: c#, .net, exception

Is the following good practice and if not what should be done?

```
catch(Exception e)
{
     throw new Exception(e.Message, e);
}
```

Comment: Really vague question.  what are you trying to accomplish?  Without knowing that, you can't have a "best practice".

Comment: I have reviewing some code that has this type of Exception Handling everywhere.  I believe it is incorrect and just using "throw;" is correct.

Comment: If it's just `catch(Exception e){throw new Exception...` then just delete the try/catch altogether.  I've seen this pattern before, I don't know where it comes from; but makes for a hell of a time debugging.  just delete the try/catch if the catch just throws (`throw;` or `throw new Exception...`)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

No, this is not good practice if you're throwing another exception of the exact same type with the same message.  In doing this, you complicate the stack trace and make debugging more of a pain.

If you're going to throw a new exception, it should differ from the original in some significant way.  It should be another type, for example, or in some other way (like a more specific error message) clarify the reason for the exception.  If you can't do either of those things, then simply rethrow the current exception using `throw;`.

Or, even better, don't catch it at all.  Rethrowing actually messes up the stack trace a tiny bit as well (the current frame's error location is set to the rethrow point rather than the spot where the exception happened), so if you don't have anything you personally have to do to handle the exception, then hands off -- just let it propagate and let the caller handle it.

Answer (score 4):

Just rethrow the exception that was caught, no need to create a new one.

```
catch(Exception e)
{
    // Do some logging...
    throw;
}
```

Some reading on rethrowing exceptions and implications on the stack trace for it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182363(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: @codingbiz: **No no no**!  That destroys the stack trace.

Comment: @SLaks Cool! Never knew that. But how please?

Comment: How what?  You just do `throw;`

Comment: what did you mean by destroying the stack trace?

Comment: What is the disadvantage of rethrowing the one above, performance, loss of data?

Comment: It doesn't preserve a lot of the information inside the exception when you do `throw e;`.  When you use `throw;`, you still get all the original data from the exception.  Read the "Rule Description" section here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182363(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: @MikeFlynn, you're not newing up a new exception, as well as you're keeping the full stack trace when using just `throw;`.

Comment: @codingbiz: When you throw an exception, it gets initialized with a stack trace that starts at the point of the throw.  If you `throw e`, that trace gets reinitialized -- and all the stack trace info already captured is lost, meaning you see no frames deeper than the throw point.  Rethrowing doesn't do that (though it does set the current frame's error location to the point of the rethrow).

Comment: @Gromer Neither is newing up an exception.  The OP's code is throwing a newly created exception, but `throw e;` would not.  It would just re-used an existing exception.  It's still undesirable though as, as has been said, the stack trace gets cleared.

Comment: I was talking about his code, as I thought that's what he was referring to.  In his code, he is newing up a new one.

Comment: @cHao Correct! I used to experience that but I didn't understand whether it's normal or not. You've just saved me some future headache

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you are trying to do.  That exact code would be pointless, but something like

```
catch(Exception ex)
{
    throw new ApplicationSpecificException("Error while doing something specific: " + contextualData, ex);
}
```

will help tremendously while debugging.

Comment: Actually his code isn't *pointless*, it does the opposite.  It would turn an `ApplicationSpecificException` into a plain ol' `Exception`, which is likely worse than just doing nothing.

Comment: @Servy - That is still [pointless](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/pointless).

Answer (score 1):

If you need do something with the exception before re-throwing it, do this:

```
catch(Exception e)
{
     // Additional handling here
     throw;
}
```

`Throw` by itself simply re-throws the current exception.  If you don't need to handle it here, don't catch it in the first place.

Also, in your example you are catching any type of exception but throwing in its place a generic `Exception` - probably not very useful.

Comment: What is the disadvantage of rethrowing the one above, performance, loss of data?

Comment: Yes, loss of data, specifically the stack trace.  By doing `throw e`, you are starting the stack trace over.  By doing just `throw` instead, the stack trace from the underlying exception is preserved.

Answer (score 0):

If the code really is just:

```
try
{
  // something
}
catch(Exception e)
{
  throw new Exception(e.Message, e);
}
```

Just delete the try/catch, it's not doing anything productive.  Exchanging `throw;` for the `throw new...` is *better*, but still not productive.

if there's something else going on in the catch, do as Gromer details, and just use `throw;`